# Repeating background using dpi images

Tags: android, bitmap

I use to do this to create a repeating background:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_pattern"
    android:tileMode="repeat | mirror" >
</bitmap>
```

According to what I know about repeating bitmaps is that the `src` has to be a *no-dpi* drawable so it doesn't stretch while being rendered.

And it was always ok, until now. This time I really need to have different drawables for the different dpi's. Does anyone know some way to do it?

Comment: What you're saying is if you put the drawable in the respective dpi drawable folder does not work?

Comment: No, it never worked with me, I always needed to put the images in `drawable-nodpi` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:
I put the drawable repeat.xml and the image in each dpi folder

repeat.xml in res/drawable-mdpi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >
</bitmap>
```

repeat.xml in res/drawable-xhdpi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/cabeca3_96x96"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >
</bitmap>
```

Resource folders:
[image]

**mdpi screenshot:**

[image]

**xhdpi screeshot:**

[image]